# why react native pickerIOS dont have dropdown icon?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

*I am using Picker component in native-base. In android picker component shows the dropdown icon but in IOS it did not show.*

Comment: Because picker in ios isn't a button with arrow. Is something like this https://codewithchris.com/img/uipickerview/UIPickerView_simulator_SwiftBlog.jpg

Comment: is it possible to add a arrow in pickerIOS?

Comment: NO, you can add a custom button with a custom arrow and in the buton action show the picker. I commend you add a library like `react-native-wheel-picker` to work with a standard style and from that to create your own design. It is better to consider both cases (ios, android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Possible in Android.But in ios it's in development. we expect that feature available in future.